# victoria hdd/ssd repair: what is the difference between "DDD (API)" vs "wr LBA num" in write mode

Tags: windows, hard-drive, repair

Does anyone know what the "DDD (API)" vs "wr LBA num" option is for in Victoria's "write" mode?

what is the difference between both?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The **Write** + **DDD** mode is "Data Distortion Detection".  Victoria writes `AA 55 AA 55 AA 55` pattern to a block (a number of sectors), and then  immediately reads it (warning user if the read
   operation returned something else).

   - The author explained it [here](https://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&topic=50045&start=560#14).
   - This mode works notably slower that regular Read / Write modes (~70MBps max vs ~300MBps, for example).
   - Some web sites (examples: [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20220426074459/https://sector.biz.ua/docs/stiranie_diska_v_victoria/stiranie_diska_v_victoria.phtml#.YmejInbP1qZ), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20220630050316/https://lumpics.ru/victoria/)) incorrectly claim that this mode overwrites the data several time or somehow otherwise makes sure that the preexisting data is "better destroyed" than with the normal Write mode.
2. The **Write** + **wr LBA num** writes some "unique" piece of information to the very beginning of each sector (the rest is still a simple `00 00 00 00 00 00` pattern)

   - This mode could be potentially used to override some simple deduplication algorithms that are built into some SSDs, like [Phison SmartZIP](https://www.ixbt.com/data/durawrite-smartzip-review.html). However, the data being written is still easily compressible and contains a lot of plain zeros, so some other controllers (e.g. with Kingston [DuraWrite](https://media.kingston.com/images/ssd/technicalbrief/MKF_612_SSDWhatisDuraWriteTechBrief-lr.pdf)) would not be fooled by it.
   - One can use the "Disk Editor" built into Vicroria 5.37 to check the actual contents of the sector:

[image: Victoria 5.37 Disk Editor shows "wr LBA num" result]

3. The **Verify** mode, btw, asks your disk to read sectors, but the data is not transferred to the host (unlike the regular **Read** mode)

   - This mode does NOT check the contents of the data anyhow (except for the disk's internal checksumming).
   - Some web sites incorrectly claim that this mode first writes and than reads some data.
   - This mode is known to not work correctly on some disks (e.g. some SSDs).
   - This mode could be useful if you're limited by your SATA/SAS/IDE/USB/etc. interface bandwidth).